# Remove persistent products from cart when logged in during checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a `woocommerce` based website where I want to remove all previous cart items when the user logs in during checkout. 
I've made login mandatory so there might be a lot of users logging in during checkout.

**Example**
User x logged in and added a product to cart.

```
2 Bags
```

User x logged out after a while and added a product to cart without logging in

```
1 Tshirt
```

During checkout when asked to log in, this is what his cart looks like

```
2 Bags
1 Tshirt
```

This is what I want

```
1 Tshirt
```

**What I Tried**
The code below works but the problem is it deletes the cart content when logged in from any page. I only want it to work on checkout page.

```
function clear_persistent_cart_after_login( $user_login, $user ) {

       $blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
         if ( metadata_exists( 'user', $user->ID, '_woocommerce_persistent_cart_' . $blog_id ) ) {
        delete_user_meta( $user->ID, '_woocommerce_persistent_cart_' . $blog_id );
    }


}
add_action('wp_login', 'clear_persistent_cart_after_login', 10, 2);
```

I tried checking for `url` but its not working

```
function clear_persistent_cart_after_login( $user_login, $user ) {
  $current_url = get_permalink();
  if($current_url  == "http://website.com/checkout/"){
       $blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
         if ( metadata_exists( 'user', $user->ID, '_woocommerce_persistent_cart_' . $blog_id ) ) {
        delete_user_meta( $user->ID, '_woocommerce_persistent_cart_' . $blog_id );
    }
  }

}
add_action('wp_login', 'clear_persistent_cart_after_login', 10, 2);
```

I did find articles somewhat related to the topic but because of my basic woocommerce knowledge, I am not able to capitalize it.
1. [Clear persistent carts for customers(users signed up over 30 days ago)](https://gist.github.com/maxrice/7dc500cd07fa70e2fb5251293d22e485) 
2. [Related issue but not exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676645/delete-previous-items-from-cart-when-user-logs-in-again-in-woocommerce)

Any help is appreciated